# Composite component in Storybook throws error

Tags: next.js, storybook

I have a parent and a child stories that I want to use in one another:

```
import React from 'react';
import type {Meta, StoryObj} from '@storybook/react';
import ChildComponent from '../ChildComponent';

const meta: Meta<typeof ChildComponent> = {
  title: 'ChildComponent',
  component: ChildComponent,
  argTypes: {
    type: {
      options: [
        'star-half',
        'star-empty',
        'star-full',
      ],
      control: {
        type: 'select',
      },
    },
    fontSize: {
      control: {type: 'range', min: 5, max: 30, step: 1},
    },
    label: {
      control: 'text',
    },
  },
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof ChildComponent>;

export const ChildStory: Story = {
  name: 'Child',
  render: (args) => (
    <ChildComponent
      type={args.type}
      fontSize={args.fontSize}
      label={args.label ? args.label : args.type + ' icon'}
    />
  ),
  args: {
    type: 'star-full',
    fontSize: 16,
    label: 'great!',
  },
};

import React from 'react';
import type {Meta, StoryObj} from '@storybook/react';
import ParentComponent from '../ParentComponent';
import {ChildStory} from '../../../ChildComponent/stories/ChildComponent.stories';

const meta: Meta<typeof ParentComponent> = {
  title: 'ParentComponent',
  component: ParentComponent,
  argTypes: {
    count: {control: {type: 'range', min: 0, max: 99, step: 1}},
    position: {control: {type: 'select'}, options: ['top', 'right', 'left']},
  },
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof ParentComponent>;


export const ParentStory: Story = {
  name: 'Parent',
  render: (args) => <ParentComponent {...args} />,
  args: {
    count: 4,
    position: 'top',
    children: <ChildStory type="star-empty" fontSize={ChildStory.args?.fontSize} />,
  },
};
```

It looks like I've done everything that was in [documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-stories/stories-for-multiple-components), but it throws error inside VisualCode: `JSX element type 'IconStory' does not have any construct or call signatures.`
And inside StoryBook: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` How can I fix it?